# android language localization

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I properly set languages and folders for es, en, it and fr. Now I need to set values folder for catalan and I did it as "values-ca-rES". However, eclipse creates a file called strings.out.xml and generates an error. What I am missing? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse when you click icon Run then it will ran the file which you have selected in Package Explorer.

[image]

Just delete "strings.out.xml" and be assure you have clicked your Root Folder(Project Name) from Package Explorer while running the App.

You are Running Project with selection of String.xml like this

[image]

So just make your selection to the Root Folder(SimpleDemo  in my case).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

*.out.xml files are automatically generated by Eclipse when someone tries to run an application through an XML file.

Make sure that you delete the generated out.xml files from project directory and run your app after choosing a .java file.

Answer (score 0):

i have facing same issue

It is a bug in eclipse, you should run your application from the Java files instead of xml.

Just delete the .out file, and try running again.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when we run XML file.. delete the main.out. file (from left side). click on corresponding java file and run it.Now it will work properly.. Note: always run Java file.